# PKCS#5 padding for AES encryption in C/C++

Tags: java, c++, encryption, openssl, aes

I did `AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding` encryption in `JAVA`. Now I am looking for equivalent method in `C/C++`. I did manage to encrypt in C using the following code :

```
const unsigned char *key = (unsigned char *)"A2XTXFEQFOPZFAKXFOPZFAK5";
unsigned char input[] = {"Hello World"};
int iLen = strlen((char*)input);
int len = 0;
if(iLen % 16 == 0){
   len = iLen;
}
else{
   len = (iLen/16)*16 + 16;
}
unsigned char output[len]; //next 16bit

AES_KEY enc_key;
AES_set_encrypt_key(key, strlen((char*)key)*8, &enc_key);
int position = 0;
while(position < iLen){
    AES_ecb_encrypt(input+position,output+position,&enc_key,AES_ENCRYPT);    
    position += 16;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using padding it must **always** be added, even if the input is a multiple of the block size.

Incorrect, this is a common mistake:

```
if(iLen % 16 == 0){
    len = iLen;
}
```

Correct:

```
int blockSize = 16;
int len = iLen + blockSize - (iLen % blockSize);
```

See [PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7).