# C++ equivalent of Java encryption

Tags: java, c++, encryption, visual-c++, openssl

I have this following snippet from Java code that is used for encryption

```
public class DESUtil {

    private final static String ALGORITHM = "DES";
    private static final byte[] EncryptionIV = "12344321".getBytes();
    private static String key="1234%^&*";

    public static String encrypt(String text) {
        try {
            IvParameterSpec spec = new IvParameterSpec(EncryptionIV);
            DESKeySpec dks = new DESKeySpec(key.getBytes());    
            SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
            SecretKey securekey = keyFactory.generateSecret(dks);

            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, securekey, spec);
            byte[] data = c.doFinal(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            return new String(Base64.encode(data));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static String decrypt(String text) throws Exception{
        try {
            DESKeySpec dks = new DESKeySpec(key.getBytes());
            SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");

            Key secretKey = keyFactory.generateSecret(dks);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(EncryptionIV);
            AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = iv;
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey,paramSpec);
            byte[] data = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(text.getBytes()));
            return new String(data,"utf-8");
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

what s the equivalent of the Java encryption in C++?

This is related to Java encryption. But not sure what is the equivalent. essentially i would like the same output as Java code generates.the I tried to use Openssl to encrypt and decrypt,however it doesn't work,I'm have seen a bunch of examples of Openssl,I still didn't know what wrong I have done yet,
the code was trying to do a DES/CBC/PKCS5padding encryption

```
int encryptdate(string plaindatas, string & encryptedatas)
{
   string EncryptionIVstr = "12344321";
   string keystr = "1234%^&*";

   const char* ivcstyle = EncryptionIVstr.c_str();
   unsigned char iv[sizeof(ivcstyle)];
   std::copy(ivcstyle, ivcstyle + sizeof(ivcstyle), iv);

   const char * keycstyle = keystr.c_str();
   unsigned char key[sizeof(keycstyle)];
   std::copy(keycstyle, keycstyle + sizeof(keycstyle), key);

   const char * incstyle = plaindatas.c_str();
   unsigned char in[sizeof(incstyle)];

   std::copy(incstyle, incstyle + sizeof(incstyle), in);

   int written = 0, temp;
   unsigned char * outbuf = new unsigned char[1024 + EVP_MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH];

   EVP_CIPHER_CTX * ctx;
   ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
   EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_des_cbc(), NULL, key, iv);


   EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(ctx, EVP_PADDING_PKCS7);

   if (!EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, &outbuf[written], &temp, in, sizeof(in)))
   {
       EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ctx);
       return -1;
   }

   written += temp;

   if (!EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, outbuf, &written))
   { 
       EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ctx);
       return -1;
   }


   EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ctx);

   encryptedatas = base64_encode(outbuf, sizeof(outbuf));
   return 0;
}


int decryptdate(string encryptdatas, string & decryptdatas)
{
    string EncryptionIVstr = "12344321";
    string keystr = "1234%^&*";

    const char* ivcstyle = EncryptionIVstr.c_str();
    unsigned char iv[sizeof(ivcstyle)];
    std::copy(ivcstyle, ivcstyle + sizeof(ivcstyle), iv);

    const char * keycstyle = keystr.c_str();
    unsigned char key[sizeof(keycstyle)];
    std::copy(keycstyle, keycstyle + sizeof(keycstyle), key);

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX * ctx;
    ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_des_cbc(), NULL, key, iv);

    std::string decodestr = base64_decode(encryptdatas);
    const char * ciphertextcstyle = decodestr.c_str();
    unsigned char ciphertext[sizeof(ciphertextcstyle)];

    std::copy(ciphertextcstyle, ciphertextcstyle + sizeof(ciphertextcstyle), ciphertext);

    int len;

    int plaintext_len;

    unsigned char * plaintext = new unsigned char[1024 + EVP_MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH];

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(ctx, EVP_PADDING_PKCS7);

    if (!EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, plaintext, &len, ciphertext, sizeof(ciphertext)))
   {
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ctx);
        return -1;
    }

    plaintext_len = len;

    if (!EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, plaintext + len, &len))
    {
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ctx);
        return -1;
    }


    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ctx);

    decryptdatas = reinterpret_cast<char*>(plaintext);
    return 0;
}
```

the consequences of Java code which DES/cbc/pkcs5padding was

```
08yw6mx6giw/tzhQk3ivwQ==
```

while the consequences of C++ code was

```
e4CsOw==
```

any idea?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37145563/pkcs5-padding-for-aes-encryption-in-c-c  Also not sure but `PKCS5Padding` vs `EVP_PADDING_PKCS7`

Answer (score 1):

There are some errors in the `encryptdate`-method:

- The `sizeof`-operator returns the size of an object or type (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof)). This operator is often used incorrectly in the code, e.g. in the following code-snippet:

  ```
  const char* incstyle = plaindatas.c_str();              // 1)
  unsigned char in[sizeof(incstyle)];                     // 2)               
  std::copy(incstyle, incstyle + sizeof(incstyle), in);   // 3)
  ```

  Here you try to copy the content of `plaindatas` (which contains the plaintext) into the array `in`. In `1)` `incstyle` is a pointer (`char*`) and therefore has a size of 4 bytes or 8 bytes (depending on whether 32-bit- or 64-bit-OS). `sizeof(incstyle)` returns this size and not the length of the string. Therefore, in `2)` an array is defined which is generally too small and thus, in `3)` only a part of the content of `plaindatas` is copied into this array.

  The array `in` is correctly filled with e.g. the following code:

  ```
  const char* incstyle = plaindatas.c_str();
  int in_len = plaindatas.length(); // Number of characters (without terminating 0)
  unsigned char *in = new unsigned char[in_len + 1];
  std::copy(incstyle, incstyle + in_len + 1, in);
  ```
- When calling `EVP_EncryptUpdate` the plain text length is also determined wrong with the `sizeof`-operator (because the length of the array `in` has already been determined incorrectly before):

  ```
  EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, &outbuf[written], &temp, in, sizeof(in))
  ```

  Rather, it should be as follows:

  ```
  EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, outbuf, &temp, in, in_len)
  ```
- There are further errors in the call of `VP_EncryptFinal_ex`

  ```
  if (!EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, outbuf, &written)) {...}
  ```

  which must actually be as follows:

  ```
  if (!EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, outbuf + temp, &temp)){...}
  written += temp;
  delete in;
  ```

  Here you have to pay attention to the update of the ciphertext length (`written`) at the end. In addition, the allocated memory for `in` can be released here so that no memory leak occurs.
- For the-Base64 encoding the length of the ciphertext is determined incorrectly again with the `sizeof`-operator:

  ```
  encryptedatas = base64_encode(outbuf, sizeof(outbuf));
  ```

  Instead, it has to be:

  ```
  encryptedatas = base64_encode(outbuf, written); 
  delete outbuf;
  ```

  Here, the allocated memory for `outbuf` can be released so that no memory leak occurs.
- With these changes, the following plain text:

  ```
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
  ```

  provides the following ciphertext:

  ```
  lXrmm21mt/5nd+bFm13mmXs+Kca4/wH1ZkbHXNe5/dPkIil7Vr7VuwQ8SeaLvMEh
  ```

  in accordance with the Java code, if the same key and IV are used. Btw for the testing I used the Base64-encoding from [base64 decode snippet in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180947/base64-decode-snippet-in-c).

I only briefly skimmed over the `decryptdate`-method. Also here the `sizeof`-operator is used incorrectly. Further errors not excluded.

Besides the mentioned bugs the code is also unnecessarily complicated and should be revised if possible. There is a detailed OpenSSL-C/C++-example [here](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) for AES-256 in CBC-mode that can be used as a blueprint (where `EVP_aes_256_cbc()` has to be replaced by `EVP_des_cbc()`, and of course IV and key). Btw DES is insecure and outdated (see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard)).